# How to extract a vector from a large matrix by index in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, extract

I am stucked with this issue in MATLAB for long now and I hope to find a help here!

I have a very large matrix with 4 vectors in it (each vector is a column) and 72300 rows .. the first column/vector is the index of the data .. so it is something like this: (example is simplified)

```
Index, Info1  Info2  Info3
1      2      1      1
1      4      5      3
1      2.5    1.3    8
2      1      4      7
2      4      6      9
2      12     3      7
3      2      6      6
3      2      1      4
3      1      4      7
```

Q1> How can I extract all Info2 with the index==3 from this matrix?

Q2> Is there any method to rearrange the matrix to be like this?

```
Index,   Info1,   Info2 Info3   Index   Info1   Info 2  Info 3
 1                              2
```

and so on ..

I hope to find some help from you guys and many many thanks in advance..

kind regards,

Comment: No idea what you are asking for in Q2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 :

For you question 1, I use a simple example because I don't have your variable name.

```
idx = find( VectorName(:,1) == 3 ) % Find in all row at column 1 where = 3 (Index)
```

After you have the index of all row where index == 3. So extract info2 value

```
AllInfo2 = VectorName(idx,3); % Get all value where row == idx and column = 3 (Info2)
```

Comment: There is no need to use `find`, logical indexing allows `idx =  VectorName(:,1) == 3`

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is simply used :) I like to use find. And I still thinking about Q2. A count max unique index to get resize the matrix, but I don't have good idea how to do it.

Comment: I'll think about something for your second question. But take in mind about function `unique` on column index and `count` so you will be able to create a new matrix NxM depending on those number.

Comment: @Leo: For Q2, assuming the numeric data is separate from the header, you can have a single row with your data strung out by `out = reshape(VectorName.',1,[]);`. That says 1 row, however many columns it takes, reading the data across.

Answer (score 3):

Q1 `>> x = A(A(:1)==3,3); % Info2 for Index==3`

Q2 `>> B = reshape(A.',1,[]); %Flatten A along the rows`